# Interfaces and async practices

Tags: c#, async-await, interface

I have an interface

```
public interface IUserFactory
{
       User GetUser(string id);
       void DeleteUser(string id);
}
```

Current class which implements uses functions which are synchronous.

I am now going to have an implementation which uses HttpClient, whose calls are async.

What I’m doing now is to have the new UserFactoryWeb class implement two sets of functions:

```
Task<User> GetUserAsync(string id)
Task DeleteUserAsync(string id)
```

and

```
User GetUser(string id)
void DeleteUser(string id)
```

the interface methods. In the interface methods I use the trick:

```
var t = Task.Run(async code...)
t.Wait();
```

in order to prevent deadlocks.

Are there other options?

Also, how can you support async calls in interfaces? It seems crazy that async isnt part of an interface signature.

Comment: What do you expect `async` on interface definition should do? Returning `Task<T>` (as every interface that has chance of async implementations do) means "result may or may not be available yet, wait for completion of this task to get one"... but what exactly `async` should add to that?

Comment: You generally shouldn't run async code in sync methods. The Task.Run is a way to do it but it can lead to deadlocks. If you are running a in asp.net core you could do a Middleware that loads the user into a context. My guess is you should be caching the user info anyways so this sort of makes sense being sync, but it's probably really old interface.

Comment: For example you will find this in most authentication and authentication handles where the async part is in pipeline on requests. All the info gets stored in User Identity and you use it synchronously. You could also use dependency injection async creation patterns it all depends on the use case. Could you share more info on the interface.

Comment: `t.Wait();` is blocking call

Comment: @FilipCordas - I thought that running an async task via Task.Run is the way to avoid deadlocks.

The issue is that I would have to change the interface to:
Task<User> GetUser
Task DeleteUser

And then update all implementations, including sychronous ones to support it.

Comment: @bpeikes the deadlock is dependent on [task scheduling used and some other things](https://medium.com/rubrikkgroup/understanding-async-avoiding-deadlocks-e41f8f2c6f5d). If rewrite of the interface is possible you should do it, As mentioned the only other way I can see this working correctly is context based Middleware.

Answer (score 3):

Let's rationalise why interfaces don't need the `async` keyword

1. A *Method* returning a `Task` / `ValueTask` does not need to be an *Async Method* (a method with the `async` keyword).
2. An *Async Method* is basically compiler plumbing to help with

   1. The return `Task` / `ValueTask` (when not void),
   2. Placing exceptions on a returned `Task` / `ValueTask` (when not void)
   3. Allowing the use of the `await` keyword
3. An *Async Method* runs *synchronously* until it hits the first `await` expression, at which point the method is suspended until the awaited task is complete.
4. An *Async Method* does not need an `await`, in which case it’s just compiler plumbing for the return value and exception when not void (see point `1.1` and `1.2` respectively)
5. You can use `await` on anything the supports the `INotifyCompletion` and the return type exposes 3 members

   - IsCompleted
   - OnCompleted
   - GetResult
6. `Task` and `ValueTask` can be *awaited* regardless of whether they were returned by an *Async Method* (see point 5)
7. *Interfaces* are just contracts between the *implementer* and the *caller* and give no indication of how the contract is *implemented*, they just contain definitions for a group of related functionalities
8. The definition of such members need no guaranteed on whether the method has been plumbed up with an `async` keyword (or whatever funky things you do in that method) just that that it returns a `Task` / `ValueTask`

In short the `async` keyword is an implementation detail, the contract is just a definition, the definition doesn’t care what you do in your method. However, if you do, or you would like your callers to know this, you document well.

To prove this, the `async` keyword has no actual bearing on the compilation of a method signature or how the callee invokes it. Let's look at the [compiled code here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEECsBuWIDMyyIGFEBvWRcxMi8nZCANmQA5lGAVAUwGcAXCACgCUVaqRgiKAXwk1cKRq0SdeYITJLqKIAOysAdAQD2AWwAOAGw48OAExD1MMauWlOKE2iAAsiALJCNNxdYSSA). You will notice the method actually loses the `async` keyword and just returns a task. However, the compiler does to a lot of other plumbing to implement the language feature.

A method such as

```
public static async Task Test1()
```

Is actually compiled to

```
[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<Test1>d__0))]
public static Task Test1()
```

---

**Additional Resources**

- [async (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async)
- [await operator (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await)
- [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)
- [Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/)
- [Stephen Toub - await anything;](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-anything/)

Comment: What happens when it does return void?

Comment: @bpeikes it still doesn't need `async` in the interface definition, interfaces are just contracts, not implementation details

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your return type to Task like:

```
public interface IUserFactory
{
       Task<User> GetUser(string id);
       Task DeleteUser(string id);
}
```

Comment: This seem to be exactly what OP already proposed... The way I understood the question is they are concerned by lack of `async` in interface definition itself... (but that's how I read the question)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `async` to a method signature does not change the contract of a method at all. There is no `async` equivalent in IL at all. The implementation of the `async` language feature is entirely in the C# compiler.

This is fairly simple to demonstrate with a simple example and an IL [de-compiler](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwKwG5nJQDMmM6AwugN7Lp2YlQAcmAbOgKIAeAhgLYAHADYBTOAAoo7AC4BKdAF4AfJgCc6afiT0GbTr0GiYkmfOUatAXyA==).

```cs
public class C {
    public async Task Example1(Task t) => await t;
    public Task Example2(Task t) => t;
}
```

```cs
// snip
public Task Example1(Task t)
// snip
public Task Example2(Task t)
// snip
```