# Why does the compiler not throw an error when an interface method is not implemented?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

I have a class `SomeRepository` which inherits from a generic abstract class `RepositoryBase<T>` AND implements an interface `ISomeRepository`.

Both the interface and the abstract class define a method called `Get` with the same parameter types and the same return type, the only difference being that in the abstract class defines it as `async` whereas the interface does not. The abstract class method is defined as `virtual` and has an implementation.

Here is what the code looks like (redacted, of course):

```
public interface ISomeRepository
{
    Task<SomeType> Get(string url);
}


public abstract class RepositoryBase<T>
{
    //private members

    //protected constructor

    public virtual async Task<SomeType> Get(string url)
    {
        //implementation
    }

    //other methods
}


public class SomeRepository : RepositoryBase<SomeType>, ISomeRepository
{
    public SomeRepository(params) : base(params)
    {
    }
}
```

As shown above, the `SomeRepository` class does NOT implement the `Get` method. In fact, it has no methods at all and only an empty constructor.
The compiler does not seem to mind this, i.e **it throws no error even though the method is not implemented**. How is this possible?

This did not bother me until I tried to change the method name in all of the above cases to `GetByUrl` (in order to comply with .NET coding standard CA1716). Only then, all of a sudden, did the compiler decide to throw an error about the method not being implemented.
I don't want to break the application by adding an implementation that hides the base class implementation.
What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the interface to a have a generic parameter, and then implement on `SomeRepository` class.

Comment: Ok, but then why did the compiler start complaining once I changed the name of the method? (Just to clarify, I changed it in all three places)

Comment: @Maya, you should change the interface to a Generic typed interface.
`public interface ISomeRepository<T>
    {
        Task<T> GetByUrl(string url);
    }`

Comment: You are right, but you didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

`SomeRepository` does implement `Task<SomeType> Get(string)` because it inherits it from `RepositoryBase<SomeType>`.

The `async` keyword does not form part of the signature and is not part of the contract. It is an implementation detail.

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65947762/5844190) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, but again, that does not answer my question about why changing the method name (in all three cases) caused the compiler to start complaining.

Comment: Did you change it in both `ISomeRepository` and `RepositoryBase<T>`? I renamed Get to GetByUrl in this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EgbdMS) and it compiles, as expected. You only get the error if you rename only one of them, or you change the signature in some other way (e.g. different return type or parameter types).

Comment: I did rename it in all three places (the interface, the base class, and the inheriting class.) I still have no idea why it only started complaining then.